# clang++ fails to compile simple hello world c++ program

Tags: 14.04, c++, clang

After upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04 clang++ stopped working.

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

$ clang++ test.cpp 
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated
```

Installed with `apt-get install clag-3.5` same happened with clang-3.4

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to compile it with `g++`? if not use `sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-dev`

Comment: of course g++ works...

Comment: @Artyom I am see this problem on TravisCI. Everything I am reading tells me I need to compile the libc++ lib separately for Clang.

Comment: For those who are looking for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111549/travis-ci-with-clang-3-4-and-c11.

Answer (score 3):

I found to resolve this issue that after installing `libstdc++-4.8-dev` package, I need to specify the  include paths and lib path to the clang++ like this.

```
clang++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.8/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: I found another way.   "clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test"

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Make sure you have libstdc++-dev installed. It's a virtual package, and in my case (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) having 4.8 works.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-dev
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: Just "sudo apt-get install libstdc++-dev" may work. It works for me, but there may be another package missing in your case.